# How to get sub-totals in Tableau text tables

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to get the subtotals for each of the groups in a tableau chart. Here is what I have thus far:

[image]

How would I get the totals for each of the studios? For example:

```
Studio           Title         #
Paramount        --            12
                 Homecoming    4
                 Titanic       8
```

Is it possible to add a "totals" row anywhere here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go into the **Analysis** menu and click Totals to modify which subtotals or grand totals are shown:

[image]